# Spring Boot - WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (Correction)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

> I am new to Spring boot and I just want to add a View for my Application. I 
>   found a question similar to mine but the information is not complete.
>   I just want to map my "/" to "springbootapplication.html". When I try localhost:8080
>   with this  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
    package com.spring.springbootapplication.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/springbootapplication.html");
    }
}
```

> It returns whitelabel Error Page. Should I add @Controller
>   Requestmapping("/")?

Here is the structure of my project:
[image: springbootapplication Poject Structure]

Comment: Why you didn't use `@Controller` ?

Comment: Oh, should I use @Controller?

Comment: If you have some model and want to show some data in html, then you should use mvc architecture. where `Mode-View-Controller` tied each other.

Comment: This might help : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Thymeleaf` dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org) is a powerful template engine just like JSP, but much better.

Place your `springbootapplication.html` is in `src/main/resources/templates`

You add a controller:

```
@Controller
public class ViewController{ 
  @GetMapping("/")
  public String index(){
    return "springbootapplication";
  }
}
```

Remove the `WebConfig` class, its not required.

Run the main class and navigate to http://localhost:8080/